# What node can do CMVision blob tracking?

Tags: ros, cmvision, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got CMVision blob tracking to work (Ubuntu 10.04 & Diamond ROS), now I could really use a node to read subscribe to the published blobs, and publish R/C servo camera tracking.
I've started to write a node, and I've studied the headers, but it's not clear to me what structure I need for the blobs.  If I can subscribe to the blobs, I can work out the centroid of the biggest blob or two, and then probably publish a servo command to the ros_arduino_bridge.

Surely there is already a node to read the blobs that I can use or study!

Thanks,

Alan KM6VV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59265/what-node-can-do-cmvision-blob-tracking?/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean CMVision was running locally, or in ROS already?  There is a node here:
http://wiki.ros.org/cmvision
And a tutorial here:
http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Detect_Blobs_using_ROS_Package_cmvision
I'm not sure if that is what you are asking though.

HTH,
James Bruce

---

Originally posted by [James Bruce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13486/james-bruce/) with karma: 16 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0